# How to use nginx as proxy to s3 aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-s3

I try to build nginx in docker as proxy to aws s3.

The problem is there is a variables that I don't understand where they come from?

First, this is how my bucket look like:

[image]

Inside this bucket I have `pic.png` file.

When I using nginx I start from docker using docker-compose:

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./example.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
```

And I start the docker using `docker-compose up`.

I have my aws_access_key and aws_secret_key from IAM key.

[image]

This is how I defined my example.com.conf file:

```
server {                                                                                                
    listen       80;                                                                                    
    server_name  localhost;                                                                             

    location ~ '^/([^/]+)/(.*)$' {
            set $bucket 'my-bucket';
            set $key '';

            # Setup AWS Authorization header
            set $aws_signature '';

            # the only reason we need lua is to get the current date
            set_by_lua $now "return ngx.cookie_time(ngx.time())";

            #the  access key
            set $aws_access_key 'AKIA6*******';
            set $aws_secret_key '1wLXpiNN0***********';

            # the actual string to be signed
            # see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html
            set $string_to_sign "$request_method\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:$now\n/$bucket/$key";

            # create the hmac signature
            set_hmac_sha1 $aws_signature $aws_secret_key $string_to_sign;
            # encode the signature with base64
            set_encode_base64 $aws_signature $aws_signature;
            proxy_set_header x-amz-date $now;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "AWS $aws_access_key:$aws_signature";

            rewrite .* /$key break;

            # we need to set the host header here in order to find the bucket
            proxy_set_header Host $bucket.s3.amazonaws.com;
            rewrite .* /$key break;

            # another solution would be to use the bucket in the url
            # rewrite .* /$bucket/$key break;

            proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com;
        }

}
```

But I getting error when I run docker with nginx:

```
 nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_by_lua" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:13
```

So I'm not sure I doing this right.
I need an explanation and an example of how to do it right please.
for example what is $key? what the the request should look like? `http://localhost:8080/pic.png`?

Comment: ngx_devel_kit module is required then you can use set_by_lua

Answer (score 1):

try to use nginx with lua installed:

```
web:
  image: firesh/nginx-lua
  volumes:
    - ./example.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
```

the problem is `set_by_lua`  need `nginx` to be compiled with `ngx_devel_kit`

**UPDATE**

it seems that you miss many modules , I suggest you to use this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/blob/master/centos/Dockerfile)

example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/example.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf openresty/openresty:centos
```

Comment: try to run `docker pull firesh/nginx-lua`then run your compose

Comment: Another problem now: ` nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_hmac_sha1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:24`.

Comment: you need to start using google then .....https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#installation

Comment: Because I not sure how this dockerfile should look. Can you please provide my an example of the all modules that required to use, if not I will looking but I not sure what to look. The only problem is I have missing modules?

Comment: you need to get nginx started then you can see what errors you got

Comment: Not working with Dockerfile example:I create Dockerfile and paste the content of Dockerfile link in your message. then I run 
`docker run -p 8080:80 -v /example.com.conf:/openresty/conf/nginx.conf openresty/openresty:centos`
The docker is running but when I open localhost:8080 I get "Welcome to OpenResty!" screen, so I think it may not read my conf file.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using lua for proxying S3 is to use [njs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/) to do the proxying. [This project](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/) shows an example with nginx proxying S3 and running in Docker.